# How to add internet privileges to LG web app?

Tags: web-applications, permissions, privileges, webos, lg

I am developing a web app for TV and I need to add internet privileges for the same. For samsung, in Tizen Studio it's quite straight forward, in IDE in config.xml we can add internet privileges. How do I do the same for LG Web OS IDE? How, where and which file should be created or modified so that my web app has internet privileges while running on tv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special permission required in webOS to access internet. For other configurations you can have a look at [appinfo.json](https://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-developer-guide/app-metadata/)